# how to rotate images with php while uploading?

Tags: php, iphone, image, rotation, image-uploading

I have an upload script for uploading images to my server to show them in a slideshow on a webpage. Unfortunately uploaded images of iPhones are displayed in the wrong orientation.
That´s why I want to rotate the images while uploading them:
Is this possible?

this is my code:

```
 <?php
 $upload_folder = 'uploads/prints/'; //Das Upload-Verzeichnis
 $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//check extensions
$allowed_extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
if(!in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {
 die("Ungültige Dateiendung. Nur png, jpg, jpeg und gif-Dateien sind erlaubt");
}

//is there an error?
if(function_exists('exif_imagetype')) { 
 $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
 $detected_type = exif_imagetype($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name']);
 if(!in_array($detected_type, $allowed_types)) {
 die("Nur der Upload von Bilddateien ist gestattet");
 }
}

//Upload path
$new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'.'.$extension;
 echo "newpath1   $new_path <br>";

//new name if filename exists
if(file_exists($new_path)) { //if yes add a number
 $id = 1;
 do {
 $new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'_'.$id.'.'.$extension;
 $id++;
 } while(file_exists($new_path));
}
 echo "newpath_2   $new_path <br>";


$FILES=$filename.".".$extension;


    $exif_data=exif_read_data($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name']);

    $Orientation=$exif_data['Orientation'];

$image=imagecreatefromstring($filename);


if(!empty($exif_data['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif_data['Orientation']) {
    case 8:

        $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
        break;
    case 3:

        $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
        break;
    case 6:
   ;
        $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);

        move_uploaded_file($image);
            echo 'Bild erfolgreich in die Schleife gelaufen : <a href="'.$new_path.'">'.$new_path.'</a><br>';
            break;
}
}

//if no rotation needed 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], $new_path);
echo 'Bild erfolgreich hochgeladen: <a href="'.$new_path.'">'.$new_path.'</a>';

?>
```

if there is no rotation needed everything is fine.
I don´t get how to combine move_uploaded_file and imagecreatefromstring or how to store the created images in my upload folder.
thanks for any hints and helps

Answer (score 0):

Use [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) to find out the orientation of the image:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('image.jpg');

if (isset($exif['Orientation']))
{
  switch ($exif['Orientation'])
  {
    case 3:
      // Need to rotate 180 deg
      break;

    case 6:
      // Need to rotate 90 deg clockwise
      break;

    case 8:
      // Need to rotate 90 deg counter clockwise
      break;
  }
}
```

for more information, please check:
http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

Comment: I already use it in the code but I don't know how to rotate the image or save the rotated in my upload folder ...